# How to Fix Wordpress App stop working after update 5.2.1?

Tags: android, wordpress, xml-rpc

I use wordpress app in android to write post and share them using the XML-RPC technology, nevertheless I have updated my website wp to 5.2.1 and all the sudden the app now is showing this error GENERIC ERROR !!!

I uninstall the app and reinstall it, now I can't even login to my website, saying this message:

```
Couldn't connect. required XML-RPC methods are missing on the server
```

how can I fix this without breaking my website!!

Comment: Did you create this app? Or is it the official WordPress app for Android you're talking about?

Comment: Hello Sir. Thank you answering me. I am using official wordpress app from Google playstore

Comment: Update: I reinstalled wordpress 5.2.1 and now the app login to my website but it only show to posts and I cant upload new posts stock at uploading since hours.

Comment: Old Posts are fetching for long time and a new post cant be uploaded .. failed to upload :/ why the heck this is happening

Comment: Try disabling all of your plugins and see if that helps. If the problem persists after that then please get in touch with the WordPress team as they're the only ones who can fix the app.

Comment: Oh, one last thing, I did upgrade to wp and to php to from 5.2 to 7.2 in cpanel, maybe this has a relationship? I dont think of any plugin, because I only use few like yoast

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I've experienced this error it's been because I didn't have the correct php modules installed on the server.

What I did which fixed it was install these two php packages:

```
sudo apt install php-xml
sudo apt install php-xmlrpc
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

While it sounds like that might not have been your problem, it's likely to be the problem for other people who find this post by searching for the error message.